# Customize Modal for a single page in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I need to display a modal as dialog so I applied some css to the modal and it works fine. But the problem is the same css is getting applied to all other modal pages irrespective of the page from which the modals are invoked. This is the css style that I uses

```
ion-modal {
        @media (min-height: 500px) {
            ion-backdrop {
                visibility: visible;
            }
        }
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: $z-index-overlay;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        contain: strict;
        .modal-wrapper {
            &,
            .ion-page,
            .ion-page .content,
            .ion-page .content .scroll-content {
                contain: content;
                position: relative;
                top: auto;
                left: auto;
            }
            z-index: $z-index-overlay-wrapper;
            display: flex;
            overflow: hidden;
            flex-direction: column;
            min-width: $alert-min-width;
            max-height: $alert-max-height;
            opacity: 0;
            height: auto;
            max-width: $alert-md-max-width;
            border-radius: $alert-md-border-radius;
            background-color: $alert-md-background-color;
            box-shadow: $alert-md-box-shadow;
            .ion-page .content {
                background-color: $background-color;
            }
        }
        ion-item {
            p {
                text-overflow: unset;
                overflow: visible;
            }
        }
        ion-label {
            overflow: visible;
            text-overflow: unset;
            white-space: normal;
        }
        .title {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .selected-card {
            border: 3px solid #488aff;
        }
    }
```

In order to make the css work it had to be applied globally since the modals live outside of the page components and that is the reason for other modals also getting the same styles. I would like to know if there is any way to achieve my aim without doing global style change. Something which can be restricted to particular page.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you please provide the modals .ts files snippet code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the the `selector` property in all of your modals `.ts` file are same and that is `ion-modal`. You may have modals like below:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'ion-modal', // check here
  templateUrl: 'a-modal.html',
})
export class AModal {
}

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'ion-modal', // check here
  templateUrl: 'b-modal.html',
})
export class BModal {
}
```

You need to give separate `selector` name in each modal like below:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'a-modal', // notice here
  templateUrl: 'a-modal.html',
})
export class AModal {
}

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'b-modal', // notice here
  templateUrl: 'b-modal.html',
})
export class BModal {
}
```

Now, change style in respective css files like below:

```
// in .scss files of AModal
a-modal{
 // your styling goes here
 .title {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
}

// in .scss files of BModal
b-modal{
 // your styling goes here
 .title {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
}
```

Now, you will get separate styling in each modals.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `ion-modal` is not the selector given in the .ts file rather its the default container created by Ionic to hold the modals. its something similar to `ion-content`

Comment: can you please paste more code and give more insight?